# How to create a moving mask showing hidden website features with vanilla html, css, js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a simple website; readable, professional colour-scheme etc.

We are trying to make it have an easter egg, so essentially:

**1.** (Upon clicking a button or something similar) the cursor becomes a circle

**2.** Through this circle, you can see a 'hidden' website (the same website as the normal one bit with a different colour scheme, little drawings and animations scattered around and within website components, different fonts etc)

The possible strategies we have come up with, and problems with each are:

**1. Strategy:** Using 'mask-position' to create a moving mask (the cursor)

**Problems:** Neither the top nor bottom layer would simply be an image. The top layer would be the basic website, and the bottom layer would be the same website but with a new colour scheme, little animations and illustrations hidden in and around the website components. Potentially the top layer could be an image of the website as it was at the time of clicking over to the new cursor, because the only bit that needs to be interacted with is whatever is inside the circle (the hidden website), but the problem with this is that the simple website still has some small things that move, which a simple image would not capture. Could potentially remove these but if there is a solution which avoids this, it is preferable, as the 'image as a top layer' solution seems clumsy and problematic anyway.

**2. Strategy:** Use an iframe to show the hidden website within the normal website.

**Problems:** However, we are unsure how to make the iframe a circle, and how to make it move (based on the cursor position).

We have not tried much as we are struggling to figure out what to try to begin with. Ie I am not sure how to make a mask-frame not using images, and I am not sure how to make a moving iframe which is also a circle.

Any advice, strategies/tricks, or even examples of what I am describing which I can use to explain/confirm the concept to others trying to work on it too would be much appreciated.

Thank you!! :)

Comment: oh yeah im not sure why it removed that, maybe because i had it in tags

Comment: it should be fixed now, thanks for pointing that out!! :D @canon

Comment: I don't think it's possible or even desirable (due to performance issues) to have two working websites layered over each other, partially occluded by a CSS mask... You're going to get so many unexpected side effects. Your idea of having the old website as an overlayed static image seems doable though! I recommend starting with a code experiment to see how that works out.

Comment: hmm @Kokodoko what about some way of telling it to generate the relevant colours/pictures/animations etc but only within the circle? so it only needs to load a small space? (but quickly, for the effect to work)

Comment: But if the circle moves fast you're going to do a lot of calculations, which impacts the performance. Your idea might work for animations that play in a HTML canvas. Again, I would recommend making a small "proof of concept" to see how far you can get with your idea. You can do that in CodePen with just a few test animations.

Comment: I have been able to do it with Iframes: https://programmingclub.com.au/portal_tests

Comment: im not sure how to see all comments, i thought i already commented this but i cant see it so apologies if im repeating, but thanks @Kokodoko for your time and help :D and thanks joey, looking forward to working on it some more with u and everyuone!! have heaps of ideas >:) (dangerous hehe)

Comment: That iframe solution is pretty cool! I'm impressed.